# Unsigned Shift Operation in Java

Tags: java, bit, unsigned

[image]

Could anybody tells me how can this Operations results "sar" a negative number?

Comment: Because that's the result of `data[0] >>> 6`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: shift negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498247/java-shift-negative-number) & [Bit wise shift operator with shift by negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15603327/876298) & [Bitwise left shift behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19839184/876298)

Answer (score 4):

`data[0]` is promoted to `int` before the shift operator is applied.

Therefore, if for example, `data[0]` is -128,

you are applying the shift on the int -128, whose binary representation is :

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000
```

This results in

```
00000011 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

And after you cast that back to `byte`, you end up with a negative number

```
                           11111110 (-2)
```

If you want to ignore the 1 bits that were added as a result of the int promotion, you can write :

```
byte sar = (byte) ((data[0]&0xff)>>>6);
```

This will result in 2 (when `data[0]` is -128).

Comment: Thank you,the only way that i can think  to make this shift behavior like normal unsigned shift in byte-range that is  [byte sar = (byte) (data[0] >>>6 && 0x3).]